# Iterating over time series

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, time, jupyter

The following is a sample of my dataset:

```html
index      time      speed
 0      00:00:00      15
 1      00:00:05      18
 2      00:00:10      23
 3      00:00:15      25
 4      00:00:20      34
```

I would like to create a for loop that does the same function as below:

```css
for i in range (0,5,1):
    if df.speed[i] > df.speed [i+2]:
         print ('Larger')
    else:
         print('Smaller')
```

However, I would like to refer to time instead of indices in the FOR loop. For example:

```html
for t in range (00:00:00, 00:00:20 , 5s):
  if df.speed[t] > df.speed [t+10s]: 
     print ('Larger')
  else:
     print('Smaller')
```

So the FOR LOOP will take the speed value at a certain t and compare with it the value of the speed after 10 seconds. If it is larger, then it prints Larger, otherwise, Smaller.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Date Range (Seconds)

It seems you're using `pandas`. If that's so, you **really** should look at it's Time Series features: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

More specific, at `pandas.date_range()`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.date_range('00:00:00', '00:00:20', freq='5s')
```

Since it's a **date** range function, it'll return datetimes

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-03-06 00:00:00',
               '2019-03-06 00:00:05',
                ...,
               '2019-03-06 00:00:20'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='5S')
```

From here just use `.strftime()` to get what you want:

`pd.date_range('00:00:00', '00:00:20', freq='5s').strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Returns

`Index(['00:00:00', '00:00:05', ..., '00:00:20'], dtype='object')`

---

### Access dataframe by time

After that, in order to access your dataframe using this index you have two options:

1. Using `.loc` to find the row where this time is:

```
for time in pd.date_range('00:00:00', '00:00:20', freq='5s').strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
    if (df.loc[df['time'] == time, 'speed'] ..):
```

2. By redefining the dataframe index with `set_index()`, and then accessing it directly by time:

```
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
for time in pd.date_range('00:00:00', '00:00:20', freq='5s').strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
    if (df.speed[time] ...):
```

---

### Edit to address comment question

After you you use `strftime()` it is converted to a String. You could convert it back to add the 10 seconds like:

`df.speed[(pd.to_datetime(time) + pd.to_timedelta(10, unit='s')).strftime('%H:%M:%S')].`

Or:

```
for time in pd.date_range('00:00:00', '00:00:20', freq='5s'):
    if (df.speed[time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')]>df.speed[(time + pd.to_timedelta(10, unit='s')).strftime('%H:%M:%S')]):
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, there is one more point I would like to know for the if condition   how to add or remove seconds on the time. for example: if (df.speed[time]>df.speed[time+ 10]) or should it be (+00:00:10), or (+'10s')?